# Add Extra Fields to Devise Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using Devise in a Rails app and need to pass an extra field (possibly) when the user logs in. If the user logs in through a subdomain, everything works. If they come in without a subdomain, I'd like for them to be required to put it into a text box. The subdomain isn't part of the user model, it's part of the organization (company). Here's the view 
```

```
<div class="row">
    <%= f.email_field :email, :class => "input_text", :placeholder=> "Email" %>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <%= f.password_field :password, :class => "input_text", :placeholder=> "Password" %>
</div>

<% if request.subdomain.blank? %>
  <div class="row">
    <%= f.text_field :subdomain, :class => "input_text", :placeholder=> "Organization" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

```

Here's the relevant parts of the user model ...

```

```
devise :token_authenticatable, :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :lockable, 
  :authentication_keys => [:email], :request_keys => [:subdomain]

def self.find_for_authentication(conditions={})
  conditions[:organization_id] = Organization.find_by_subdomain(conditions[:subdomain]).id
  conditions.delete(:subdomain)
  super(conditions)
end
```

```

I end up with subdomain being undefined for a nil class in the view.

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: If anyone's interested, I ended up not doing things this way at all. The best way we could find, was to essentially grab the url from the form and add appropriate subdomain in there. If anyone asks, I'll outline it further in an answer.

Comment: When you use request_keys you don't have to use the f.text_field. You could also use Organization.find_by_subdomain(conditions.delete(:subdomain)) to shorten the self.find_for_authentication.